# PropertyWrapper initialization with custom type initialization

Tags: swift

I want propertyWrapper initialization with custom type initialization, here is my propertyWrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper struct Round {

    var roundDigits: Int
    var wrappedValue: Double
    
    var projectedValue: String? {
        get { return String(format: "%0.\(roundDigits)f", wrappedValue) }
    }

    init(wrappedValue: Double, roundDigits: Int) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        self.roundDigits = roundDigits
    }

    init(roundDigits: Int) {
        self.wrappedValue = 0
        self.roundDigits = roundDigits
    }
 
}
```

and this is my struct:

I cannot make the this part build because i am using self before initialization. How can I solve this issue?

```
struct CustomType {

    var name: String
    var roundDigits: Int
    // I want use roundDigits for feeding @Round
    @Round(roundDigits: 2) var value: Double

    init(name: String, roundDigits: Int, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.roundDigits = roundDigits
        self.value = value
    // some other work that must be done here ...
    }

}
```

finally this is my use case:

```
let test: CustomType = CustomType(name: "Hello", roundDigits: 4, value: Double.pi)
print(test.name, test.$value!)

let test2: CustomType = CustomType(name: "World", roundDigits: 6, value: Double.pi)
print(test2.name, test2.$value!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to have a property of type Round in CustomType that is declared as a normal property

```
struct CustomType {
    var name: String
    var value: Round
```

And then initialize it by injecting a Round instance or creating it in the init

```
init(name: String, value: Round) {
    self.name = name
    self.value = value
}

init(name: String, roundDigits: Int, value: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self.value = Round(wrappedValue: value, roundDigits:  roundDigits)
}
```

Comment: I did accept the Answer, it is working, but if I must use propertyWrapper in this way in your answer, it makes no sense! Because it acts like an other custom type inside CustomType. I am not discussing about your answer, I am talking about the propertyWrapper inside CustomType, I would say using CustomType in this way it destroy the idea of propertyWrapper, because there is no wrapper any more and became a custom type inside CustomType.

Comment: One could one the other hand argue that if the number of decimals used when rounding is always set dynamically you are better of with a function than a property wrapper while the property wrapper is more useful when they are set once.

Comment: I know, I just tried to create an example with my question to show the issue, when we really wants initialization propertyWrapper through a Custom Type initialization. Which after all it broke.